# how do I delete firestore from firebase cli

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I don't want firestore related files available to the public, how do I delete it from firebase cli, after I had initialized firebase cli with it

Answer (score 1):

The only thing relevant to Firestore in your project folder is the Security Rules and the reference to it within the firebase.json file.

Simply delete the Firestore rules file, and edit the Firebase.json so that the firestore rules reference is removed. Just make sure that the json file is still json compliant by ensuring you only delete the correct bounding `{firestore},` nodes